# Convert BLOB jumble to 0s and 1s [byte stream to binary string]

Tags: php, mysql, binary

I have a BLOB column in my MySQL table. When I echo the value of the field using PHP I get

```
SBτF¶☼╢ñ═∩P╙  _ë    ☺K ☺♦ Å☼♂↔☻        ♥
```

Is there a way for me to convert the binary to a string of 0s and 1s?

This data is NOT an Image and NOT a text, they are small UDP packages of data where the 0s and 1s have significance and I need to load that data and interpret it

Comment: There is, but it's difficult to imagine why you would want to. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: these are small compact messages received by a gps device

Comment: You may want to check out php functions called pack, unpack and base_convert.

Comment: @Mikk yes unpack and base_convert are working, that's the answer

Comment: @Moak base_convert only works for numbers which can fit in a `double`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to this, so I'm going to reinvent the wheel a bit.

```
function binDigitsFromString($str) {
    $r = '';
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($str); $i++) $r .= sprintf("%08b",ord($str[$i]));
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: +1 I think this is what the OP meant, accessing and processing the *bytes* from the blob instead of echo'ing its content to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't supposed to enco the blob data directly, without specifying the content type in the header.

For example, if the blob consist of image data for a PNG image, you'd set the header like this:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $myBlob;
```

and that will render as an image.

This is worth a read: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-mysql-blob/

Comment: This is not an image, I really want the binary 0s and 1s

Answer (score 0):

You can Convert BLOB to Char and not to Varchar

You can use CAST function to convert the corresponding value to Character set utf8

Comment: The data is not text, not an image I really need the 0s and 1s